# Reformatting a JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON response here,

```json
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Key": {
        "timestamp": "2022-11-06T20",
        "value": 100.80
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": {
        "timestamp": "2022-11-07T08",
        "value": 100.90
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That I would like to reformat to this:

```json
{
  "Key": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2019-01-08T20",
      "value": 12.44
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2018-12-12 16:23:00",
      "value": 12.45
    }
  ]
}
```

For all responses, the Key must only be on the top once followed by an array of timestamps and values, and remove the Items parent value completely. I have tried doing this and messing around with the implementation, but I keep receiving multiple different errors. Is this the correct idea to do it or is there a better way to implement this?

```
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonOutput);
        JObject newObj = new JObject();
        new JProperty("KEY", new JArray(
            .Children<JProperty>()
            .Select(j => new JObject(


                    new JProperty("timestamp", j.Value["timestamp"]),
                    new JProperty("value", j.Value["value"])
                    )
                )
           )
       );
       jsonOutput = newObj.ToString();
```

What is the correct way to implement this idea? Thanks!

Comment: You can create class representing both Json object and use a `SelectMany`, that will be a no brainner. Or try to navigate from `obj.SelectToken("Items").Select(i=> i.SelectToken("Key"))` or `obj["Items"].Select(i=> i.SelectToken("Key"))` . It will be a list of all key token. Then Creating the object is a simple `JObject newObj = new JObject(new JProperty("KEY", new JArray(obj["Items"].Select(i => i.SelectToken("Key")))));`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily by combining

1. [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) with a [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard operator for the `Items[*]` array to select all required JSON objects.
2. Serialization of an anonymous type object to create the required output structure.

Thus:

```
var query = obj.SelectTokens("Items[*].Key");
jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Key = query }, Formatting.Indented);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vC1HSR).

Answer (score 1):

you can fixed it in one line

```
jsonOutput = new JObject {new JProperty("Key", ((JArray)JObject.Parse(jsonOutput)
["Items"]).Select(s => s["Key"]))}.ToString();
```